# R: How to add a variable - Date - to a data frame with n obs consisting of Sys.time

Tags: r, google-trends

I am extracting Google Trends data looking at `interest_over_time` and `interest_by_city`.

I've noticed the `interest_by_city` data frame doesn't contain any date information. As I am looking to monitor the changes over time this is problematic.

Is there a way to add a new variable for the date where each observation will be the date and time the data was extracted?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to add `Sys.time()` to the data you just extracted then you can call `df$time <- Sys.time()`.